# Logs are duplcating in both the files when using log4j.properties

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Below is the log4j properties file content. I am trying to write WARN logs to two differnt different log filesBY by define two log appenders as shown below.

Problem : The logs are wrting into both the files (duplicate) .

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARN, A1, xmlout, GPSMSPLogger
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, xmlout
log4j.logger.mailLogger=ALL, mail

log4j.category.com.moodys=INFO

# Setting additivity to false
# For not writing same logs into two files
# R3'13 
log4j.additivity.org.apache=false
log4j.additivity.A1=false;
log4j.additivity.GPSMSPLogger=false;
log4j.logger.GPSMSPLogger=DEBUG,GPSMSPLogger

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.threshold=DEBUG
# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x %m%n


# xmlout is set to be a DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.xmlout=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.xmlout.Threshold=DEBUG
#log4j.appender.xmlout.Directory=e\:\\logs\\surveillance.
#log4j.appender.xmlout.Prefix=surveillance
#log4j.appender.xmlout.Suffix=.log
log4j.appender.xmlout.Append=true
log4j.appender.xmlout.layout=org.apache.log4j.xml.XMLLayout


log4j.appender.mail=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
#log4j.appender.mail.To=dmitry.nikelshpur@moodys.com
#log4j.appender.mail.To=valeriy.vinnychuk@moodys.com
log4j.appender.mail.To=Moody's-SFGSMART@moodys.com
log4j.appender.mail.From="SFG SMART Application Mailer [Dmitry Nikelshpur]"
# Q2'12
#log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=mdynycmsxswp.moodys.com
log4j.appender.mail.SMTPHost=${SMTP.MAIL.SERVER}
# Q2'12 
log4j.appender.mail.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.mail.BufferSize=1
log4j.appender.mail.Subject=Test Surveillance logger email handler *** PLEASE DISREGARD *** 
log4j.appender.mail.layout=com.moodys.sfg.smart.util.SMARTMailerHTMLLayout
log4j.additivity.mailLogger=true
log4j.appender.mail.layout.LocationInfo=true


# R3'13
# Setup GPSMSPLogger
log4j.appender.GPSMSPLogger=biz.minaret.log4j.DatedFileAppender
log4j.appender.GPSMSPLogger.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.GPSMSPLogger.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x %m%n
log4j.appender.GPSMSPLogger.Directory=${msp.log.directory}
log4j.appender.GPSMSPLogger.Prefix=gps_msp.
log4j.appender.GPSMSPLogger.Suffix=.log
log4j.appender.GPSMSPLogger.Threshold=DEBUG
```

below is the code used to log:

```
public class GPSMSPLogger {

public static Logger getLogger(){

return Logger.getLogger("GPSMSPLogger");

}

public static void main(String arg[]){

getLogger().info("Log example INFO.......... ");

}

}
```

Comment: Which loggers (not appenders) are you logging to?  Can you show the code where you call `getLogger`

Comment: Hi lan Roberts, updated post with your question

Comment: It's quite difficult to follow because of the way you have appenders and loggers with exactly the same names, but as far as I can tell that configuration _looks_ right, and should send the `Log example INFO......` only to the appender named `GPSMSPLogger`.

Comment: is it because I put ; at end for this log4j.additivity.A1=false; ??

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't spot that.  You should remove the semicolons from `log4j.additivity.A1` and `log4j.additivity.GPSMSPLogger`

Comment: Ok , let me check this

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the trailing semicolons on these lines:

```
log4j.additivity.A1=false;
log4j.additivity.GPSMSPLogger=false;
```

The additivity value should be either `true` or `false`, not `false;`

Comment: After this change, it is not duplicating in main console appender log file but logs are duplicating(console+appender) in GPSMSPLogger appender log file.